# Discordjs chane nickname in all servers every 10 / 15 seconds

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im making a bot that shows btc price in the name, I have a problem. Now the bot updates when someone sends a message, there is any way to update it every 10 / 15 secs using a function with a timeout?

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
const request = require("request");


client.on("message", message => {
    const url = "API";


    request(url, (err, res, body) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
 
        var BTC = data.price;
        message.guild.me.setNickname(BTC)

    }); 
})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

```js
function changeNickname() {
    request(url, (err, res, body) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
 
        var BTC = data.price;
        message.guild.me.setNickname(BTC)

    }); 
}

setInterval(changeNickname, 15000); // Run function every 15 seconds
```

Comment: It wont work because to change the nickname I get from were the message was sent, I need to change the way to set the nickname

Answer (score 0):

Changing your username programmatically can be accomplished via [`client.user.setUsername()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.0/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setUsername), but is limited to one change every two hours, so you won't be able to change it as often as you want to. Maybe try using statuses instead?

That said, you can modify it every two hours via `setInterval()`.

```js
setInterval(() => {
    // --- request the BTC value and assign it to the BTC variable ---
    client.user.setUsername(BTC);
}, 7200000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also attempt to use the bot's status to display this, along with a command that will manually provide the current BTC price. Code is listed below

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
const request = require("request");

client.on("ready", () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      request(url, (err, res, body) => {
          const data = JSON.parse(body);
 
          var BTC = data.price;
          client.user.setActivity(`The current Bitcoin price is: ${BTC}`, { type: "PLAYING" });
      });
    }, 15000);
});

client.on("message", message => {
    const prefix = "btc!" // You can change this to whatever
    const url = "API";

    if(message.content === "btc!price") {
    request(url, (err, res, body) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
 
        var BTC = data.price;
        message.channel.send(`The current Bitcoin price is ${BTC}`);
    }); 
    }
});

client.login(TOKEN)
```